# How to include a php template into a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to include a small navigation template file into a page in wordpress so I dont need to change it in a bunch of pages.

here is my code:

```
<div id="content_top" class="whiteBG">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                <?php get_template_part( 'subnav' ); ?>


                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium itaque dolores labore, illo nam. Aut voluptatum dicta sed sint rerum dignissimos vitae. Repellendus, harum tempora rem fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code I am trying to include is this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">button</a></li>
    <li><a href="">button</a></li>
    <li><a href="">button</a></li>
    <li><a href="">button</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_template_part() function scans your theme and child theme directories for the file.

You used it properly:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'subnav' ); ?>
```

That will look for subnav.php in your themes directory.

Since you used it properly, then maybe subnav.php doesn't exist in the themes root directory, or something else is going on.

The main function is the one you used, get_template_part(). You can also include things normally, depending on where it's used, using require_once() or file_get_contents().

```
<?php require_once('path/to/file.php'); ?>

<?php echo file_get_contents('path/to/file.html'); ?>
```

Require will allow you to pass php variables. If you use file get contents, it grabs the contents or code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer

This is what I did
http://gyazo.com/93531e6527b34ae2088bb6a09abddf8d

And this is what happened on the front end
http://gyazo.com/44e1f13b6e9159fba9d5d8a5c01af85c

Comment: You have to wrap php code with the php tags.. I'll update the answer to show the tags.

Comment: Perhaps you could answer me one last thing. How come the template file renders outside of the container I put it in?

http://gyazo.com/ca9be0f214d5fb4a1c4ceb7180e2b25a

In Console it looks like this

http://gyazo.com/83306af940acaa358f70f525e1b299c0

Comment: Go back to using `get_template_part` and make sure `subnav.php` is in your theme's root directory.